# Export PDF format

Tags: c#, xaml

My question earlier was quite vague. and i still dont know how, im new here in c#/XAML for windows 8 app. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;

namespace iTextSharpTester
{
public class PDFCreator
{
    // Set up the fonts to be used on the pages
    private iTextSharp.text.Font _largeFont = new    iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
    private iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
    private iTextSharp.text.Font _smallFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

    public void Build()
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = null;

        try
        {
            // Initialize the PDF document
            doc = new Document();
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc,
                new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\asd.pdf",
                    System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            // Set the margins and page size
            this.SetStandardPageSize(doc);
```

the problem here is that the System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, System.IO.FileStream and the System.IO.FileMode.Create. It said that those code does not exist in the namespace System.IO. THanks in advance! This is for windows 8 app. By the way, im only following an article tutorial for itextsharp. the codes are in wpf and im trying to transfer it in windows 8 app